# new solution error in xamarin for xamarin.forms portable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When creating new solutions(xamarin.forms portable) in xamarin studio.
error in package console

Could not install package 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.1.6296'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Exactly the same for me as well. :(

Answer (score -1):

In Xamarin Studio >> Project Menu >> Add Nuget Package: Check Xamarin.Forms

You can see this page too: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31490/package-installation-error-upon-solution-creation